# How can I use a sliced image As banner?

Tags: php, theme-development, headers

I am giving a try to something i have never done before. I am trying to slice a psd file and want to use it as a banner. But the problem is, as you may already know that, wordpress only allow one image as banner, so how can I use sliced psd as banner?

If coding is needed, can you give me some hints, so that I can make a try over it.

Comment: _Why_ do you need a sliced image as banner? Slicing is old school. Use sprites :)

Comment: i am slicing for having Anchors on it, i want to make clickable parts of the image

Comment: Then use an image map. Or make an invisible overlay.

Comment: Image maps are old school - don't go that route.  Sprites are the most efficient way to go, but slicing isn't evil.

Comment: FYI, WordPress itself does not "only allow one image as banner".  The THEME you are using is only set up to use one image.  It's a simple matter of editing the header.php file for your theme, and setting it up to display/link to the sliced images.

Comment: if version is needed, its 1.3 (by wordpress team)

Comment: i am using Twenty Elevan and the link to site is http://www.klusdesign.com/blog

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could avoid slicing the image by using an image map to map different parts of the image to different links.

Otherwise you will need to get into the header.php file in your theme, thats where the code that outputs the header image is. If you want to hardcode something, you can do it right there.

/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/header.php

Here's a great tool for making that image map.

http://www.maschek.hu/imagemap/imgmap

Comment: Let me know what theme you are using (I am going to guess twentyten or twentyeleven) and I can help you with some code and line numbers.

Comment: Please add those comments to the Question, not the answer.

Comment: i have mapped the banner, copied and pasted the code in header.php, but this is not working..any idea?